# Reuse Fragment View after return from back stack

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have FrameLayout and I'm loading different fragments. For example: fragment with listView and on Item selected load another fragment in the same frame. I'm adding  `fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);`
but when I press the back button when I return to fragment with the listview it starts to create all the stuff in the onCreatView and that takes tame to load the images and text again. 
How can I save that view and when return from the back stack just to load it, not creating it again.

This is my Fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_cases_atlas, container, false);
    mGridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridViewAtlasCases);

    mPullToRefreshLayout = new PullToRefreshLayout(container.getContext());
    mPullToRefreshLayout = (PullToRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ptr_layout);
    ActionBarPullToRefresh.from(getActivity())
            .options(Options.create()
                    // Here we make the refresh scroll distance to 65% of the GridView height
                    .scrollDistance(.65f)
                    // Here we define a custom header layout which will be inflated and used
                    // Here we define a custom header transformer which will alter the header
                    // based on the current pull-to-refresh state
                    .build())
            .allChildrenArePullable()
            .listener(this)
            // Here we'll set a custom ViewDelegate
            .useViewDelegate(GridView.class, new AbsListViewDelegate())
            .setup(mPullToRefreshLayout);

    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        selectedCatDTO = (CategoryDTO) bundle.get(Constants.BUNDLE_SELECTED_CATEGORY_WAITING);
    }
    ((TextViewAvenirLTStdMedium) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvSubCategoryTitle)).setText(selectedCatDTO.getName());
    ((TextViewAvenirLTStdLight) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvSubCategoryCount)).setText("( " + selectedCatDTO.getCount() + " " + getString(R.string.string_cases) + " )");

    if (SharedPreferencesManager.getCasesForCategory(getActivity(), String.valueOf(selectedCatDTO.getId())).equals("")) {
        mPullToRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        final NetworkHandler networkHandler = NetworkHandler.getInstance();
        networkHandler.readCases(new OnCaseTaskComplited(), String.valueOf(selectedCatDTO.getId()));
    } else {
        prepareCategories(SharedPreferencesManager.getCasesForCategory(getActivity(), String.valueOf(selectedCatDTO.getId())));
        setAdapterGridView();
    }

    LinearLayout llSubmitAtlas = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.llSubmitAtlas);
    llSubmitAtlas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SubmitCaseWaitingFragment fragmentSubmitCaseWaiting = new SubmitCaseWaitingFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragmentSubmitCaseWaiting).commit();
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}

private void setAdapterGridView() {
    final CasesGridViewAdapter mCustomGridAdapter = new CasesGridViewAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.cases_gridview, mCases, R.drawable.loading_text);
    mGridView.setAdapter(mCustomGridAdapter);
    mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Case caseObject = mCustomGridAdapter.getChild(position);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable(Constants.BUNDLE_SELECTED_CASE_WAITING, caseObject);
            WaitingCaseDetailsFragment fragmentWaitingCaseDetails = new WaitingCaseDetailsFragment();
            fragmentWaitingCaseDetails.setArguments(bundle);
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragmentWaitingCaseDetails).commit();
        }
    });
}
```

And this is my GridViewAdapter:

```
public CasesGridViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<Case> objects, int defaultImageResId) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, objects);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    mContext = context;
    this.cases = objects;
    this.defaultImageResId = defaultImageResId;

    // Get memory class of this device, exceeding this amount will throw an
    // OutOfMemory exception.
    final int memClass = ((ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE)).getMemoryClass();

    // Use 1/8th of the available memory for this memory cache.
    final int cacheSize = 1024 * 1024 * memClass / 8;
    mMemoryCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {

        protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
            // The cache size will be measured in bytes rather than number of items.
            return bitmap.getByteCount();
        }

    };

    mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {

        public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
            mMemoryCache.put(url, bitmap);
        }

        public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
            return mMemoryCache.get(url);
        }
    });


}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    Case caseItem = cases.get(position);

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imageTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvGridViewText);
        holder.image = (NetworkImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.ivGridViewImage);
        holder.progressBar = (ProgressBar) row.findViewById(R.id.viewProgressBar);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    holder.imageTitle.setText(caseItem.getTitle());
    try {
        String key = SomeHelp.getBlobstoreImageUrl(caseItem.getPhotos().get(0).getBlobKeyThumbnail());
        holder.image.setImageUrl(key, mImageLoader);
        holder.image.setDefaultImageResId(defaultImageResId);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_image_text);
    }
    return row;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView imageTitle;
    NetworkImageView image;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fragment is detached and the view is destroyed, imagine you have in backstack 50 fragments with all the views in memory, the app will crash. So if you have stuff that does heavy loading, save in Application object or do a cache of images/contents and later restore in "onViewCreated" If the problem is load images, consider using "picasso" or "universal image loader".

Comment: I'm using modified Volley for image loading, but it is created in onCreateView so it starts to load them again. also I need just the fragment on the top of the fragment to me save not all fragments

Comment: share some code to help you, but the idea is that you only load 1, save your response and when you need to restore the view of fragment, populate view with saved data

Comment: how do you save and populate view with the data

Comment: if you have images, you will need to cache bitmaps: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Comment: If you are working with bitmaps you will need to cache bitmaps: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html Or use the libraries I mentioned that already have cache techniques. Create view with inflater in "onCreateView" and then restore the bitmap from a Singleton instance where you have the Bitmap cache in "onViewCreated" to set bitmaps to imageView.

Comment: as you can see and as I said I'm already using the cache, but all this is recreated when onCreatView is called

Comment: Yes you have a cache, but you have the cache in adapter and is created each time you create the view of the fragment so it doesn't do the function that you need. Separate the cache from the adapter, for example move it to a custom application object (extends Application) and later access to it with ((CustomApp)getApplication()).getCache